# What's wrong with my delete method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails so this is probably easy. Can you take a look at the delete method in my code and let me know what's wrong? I've done some searching but am not finding exactly what I need to do. Basically I'm creating a twitter type site to post statuses as I'm learning.

Thanks!

```
<div class="page-header"><h1>All Statuses</h1></div>

<% @statuses.each do |status| %>
  <div>
   <strong><%= status.name %></strong>
    <p><%= status.content %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="meta"><%= link_to 'Show', status %></div>
  <div class="admin"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_status_path(status) %> | <%= link_to 'Delete', admin_status_path(status.id), :method=>delete, :class=>destroy, :confirm=>"Are you sure you want to delete this status?" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Routes.rb

```
Testing::Application.routes.draw do
resources :statuses


# The priority is based upon order of creation:
# first created -> highest priority.

# Sample of regular route:
#   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
# Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

# Sample of named route:
#   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
# This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

# Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
#   resources :products

# Sample resource route with options:
#   resources :products do
#     member do
#       get 'short'
#       post 'toggle'
#     end
#
#     collection do
#       get 'sold'
#     end
#   end

# Sample resource route with sub-resources:
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments, :sales
#     resource :seller
#   end

# Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
#   resources :products do
#     resources :comments
#     resources :sales do
#       get 'recent', :on => :collection
#     end
#   end

# Sample resource route within a namespace:
#   namespace :admin do
#     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
#     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
#     resources :products
#   end

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
# just remember to delete public/index.html.
# root :to => 'welcome#index'

# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

# This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
# Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
# match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

Comment: a side note, link_to :method => :delete will only create the expected result if javascript is enabled, as the javascript dynamically creates a form and submits it. If you want to always ensure a POST request is sent, use the button_to helper instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the colon on `delete`

```
:method => :delete
```

And the quotes on your class

```
:class => 'destroy'
```

Comment: Done. But it looks like I'm actually still getting a issue - 

undefined method `admin_status_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000104ea2e78>:0x00000104973b50>

Comment: And my code:

<div class="page-header"><h1>All Statuses</h1></div>

<% @statuses.each do |status| %>
  <div>
   <strong><%= status.name %></strong>
    <p><%= status.content %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="meta"><%= link_to 'Show', status %></div>
  <div class="admin"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_status_path(status) %> | <%= link_to 'Delete', admin_status_path(status.id), :method=>:delete, :class=>'destroy', :confirm=>"Are you sure you want to delete this status?" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New Status', new_status_path %>

Comment: What is `admin_status` by the way? Can you post your `routes.rb`

Comment: Good question - I found a bunch of examples online that added admin in front of it so I included that in :).

Comment: Its easier if you edit your original question and add the `routes.rb` contents over there. It is very difficult to read code in comments